# How to change the working directory of a tomcat server to WEB-INF of my application?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a bean class where I'm using a file that I've placed in `application/WebContent/common` folder. I have been refering to this file as below

```
File xsltfile = new File("../common/xhtml2fo.xsl");
```

in my eclipse, with my working directory configured to

```
${workspace_loc:enovia/WebContent/WEB-INF}
```

it worked fine. However, while testing it on a domain-box, I'm getting a file not found exception because its looking for the file in {tomcat-path}/bin/../common/xhtml2fo.xsl.

I don't have access to bean classes in the domain box. So my only option for now is to change my tomcat working directory to WEB-INF.

Comment: Use the relative path, Luke... Only Sith write paths in absolute.

Comment: isn't that a relative path?

Answer (score 1):

You can read files in `WEB-INF` using this approach:

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread()
                       .getContextClassLoader()
                       .getResourceAsStream( "xhtml2fo.xsl" );
```

or even simpler if you're in a servlet:

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream( "/WEB-INF/xhtml2fo.xsl" )
```

Cheers,

Comment: I think that if the resource is in the WEB-INF folder, it would be `ServletContext.getResource`. EDIT: we wrote about it just simultaneously :)

Comment: The file is tomcat/webapps/app/common folder and not in WEB-INF. That being said, right now, I can't change my code in the domain box. Is there a configuration change I can make to my tomcat server to set my application WEB-INF as the working directory, such that "../common/xhtml2fo.xsl" works?

Comment: Can you rebuild the app and deploy it with a fix or is this hardcoded stuff you can't change?

Comment: No... I can't change it without going through a day's process. :(

Comment: Well, as for now - get the file path it provides (tomcat's one), put the file over there (you can extract it from the webapps) and NEVER do this again - just fix it when you have time. Cheers.